# comparing files in python

Tags: python-3.x, file-io

What is most efficient way to looking up the names listed in a comma delimited file in text file

Comma delimited file with names:

```
abc,def,ghi
jkl,mno,pqr
stu,vwx,yza
```

Text file:

```
This is abc. Not a business of def. blah blah.
Because mno did not agree with pqr. blah blah.
stu concluded that vwx was a good choice. blah blah.
```

these files have potential to be as huge and hence looking for a scalable way to comparing them

Comment: What is wrong with the obvious solution of loading the names into a set or dictionary and iterating through the file, checking for membership in the set? This algorithm is O(m+n) where m is the number of names and n is the number of words in the text file. It isn't reasonable to expect better than linear.

Comment: @JohnColeman both the files do not have key columns, any way to do this without storing in a dictionary?

Comment: Reading the csv file into a set for lookup doesn't depend on the existence of key columns. It only takes a few lines of code to do so and is by far the only way that scales nicely. Even if the csv file is huge it takes less than a second to load into a set (I do this all the time with the word file yawl.txt which has over 200,000 entries). Once it is loaded lookup is O(1). Once such a set such as this is loaded it should only take at  most a few seconds to e.g. read in the complete text of Moby Dick and identify the set of all words in Moby Dick that occur in your word set.

Comment: If you *really* need quick lookup and you are using the same csv file with many different text files you could look into using a trie ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie ) or similar data structure, but it is hard to recoup the time invested in setting such a thing up when Python already has such a nice implementation of sets and dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

This is the sort of thing you can do:

```
def setfromcsv(fname):
    s = set()
    f = open(fname)
    lines = f.read().split('\n')
    f.close()
    for line in lines:
        s.update(line.split(','))
    return s
```

Used like this:

```
>>> words = setfromcsv("test.csv")
>>> 'def' in words
True
>>> 'dfe' in words
False
>>> print(words)
{'vwx', 'pqr', 'mno', 'abc', 'ghi', 'jkl', 'stu', 'yza', 'def'}
```

By far the trickiest thing about what you seem to want to do is to extract words from the text document that you are trying to check since you need to be careful about case and punctuation (spitting in a naïve way might Miss 'abc' in 'This is abc.' 'abc.' with the dot wouldn't be in the word set.) Regular expressions could be used, though low-tech solutions could also work.